# Solve $|2\cot4x|\ge2/\sqrt3$ for $0\le x\le2\pi$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find $x$ if 
>   $$|2\cot4x|\ge \frac{2}{\sqrt3}$$
>   and $0\le x\le2\pi$.

I have no idea how to start, i need help badly. I tried to change LHS to |cot(2x)-tan(2x)| but with no success

Comment: When figuring out stuff in inequalities, in general try first factor the expression and then make a sign change diagram of it's factors.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you can divide both sides by $2$.
Then you have to decide for with $x$ the $cot$ is greater or less than zero. For these intervals you can solve the absolute value. And then finally the inequality.

Think about, what does the $arccot$ does to an inequality? Does he preserve it or does he change it?